# Ownership conventions in C

Tags: c, ownership

Let's assume I want to use a library that contains these 2 headers:

```
// types.h
typedef const char* Value;
typedef const char* Key;

// map.h
/** The given name and value will be copied into the map */
void add(struct Map* m, Key key, Value value);
```

I'm assuming the comment means that the contents of the `char*`s `key` and `value` will be copied by the `add` function, and it won't store the pointers for use after it has returned. That means the calling function can do whatever it wants with those pointers, like e.g. `free`ing `key` and `value`, immediately after calling `add`.

The calling function can also expect that `add` will not modify `key` or `value`.

Now what would the experienced C programmer assume about these ownership issues if that comment wasn't there and neither sources of the implementation nor a usage example were available?

Comment: An explanation by the downvoter would be helpful.

Comment: *This* experienced C programmer would not assume anything, and would either test the behaviour or preferably find an alternative where the sources and/or documentation *were* available.

Comment: "what would the experienced C programmer assume" -- I would conclude (not assume) that the programmer was incompetent. (This is my conclusion about most C code I see, which lacks such comments.)

Comment: 'The calling function can also expect that add will not modify key or value.' -- Well, yes, because they are passed by value. If you mean `*key` and `*value` ... `const` strongly suggests that, but I suppose there some programmers *so* incompetent that they might store into them within `add` anyway.

Comment: 'An explanation by the downvoter would be helpful' -- Reading the FAQ would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First & foremost is to try & get the documentation. One cannot be 100% sure unless the API documents the behavior. If all attempts fail then it is reasonable to assume that:

1. Function does not modify either `Key` or `Value` since they are passed as `const`.
2. Unless explicitly mentioned the caller retains the ownership of the variables being passed to the function and can do whatever they want with the passed `Key` and `Value` after the function call.

Also, One should confirm the assumptions with rigorous testing.

Comment: +1 Sounds reasonable (to the inexperienced C programmer)

Comment: "One should confirm the assumptions with rigorous testing." -- That can only establish the *current* behavior of the library. I guess it takes something other than mere experience to understand the limitations of testing.

Comment: @Jim Balter: While UB technically means anything can happen, in this particular case one can conclusively use testing to determine the behavior. I don't know what the second sentence intends to say so I will just pass that one. Unlike you I won't guess. Hth.

Comment: It's tragic that you don't know what it means, because it's a fundamental concept of software engineering. Again, testing can only establish the *current* behavior of a library ... but the behavior of a library can change at any time. The only thing that reliably won't change is the specification. Testing is only good for a developer testing that his/her implementation meets the specification; it is not good for the use here.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would expect it to copy the values. Because if it wouldn't it would be very dangerous to use with local variables.

Also, in case of a map, you would have to track all the elements and how they where allocated and free them yourself after freeing the map if the copy wouldn't happen.